# (Android) How to set status bar color black in transparent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, statusbar, transparent

There is a transparent activity A.

A is using Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar in AndroidManifest to be transparent.

What I want is to change status bar color to black remaining activity transparent.

Please help.

Comment: What do you refer to really, status bar or action bar?

Comment: Just wanted to be clear, the answer below should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, clearly works, but I need solution when api-level is under 21

Comment: This is not possible pre-lollipop, since that is when we are able to adjust the status bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From android Api-Level 21  you can use

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

select black

```
android.R.color.black
```

To show and hide the status bar

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Thanks but what if Api-Level is under 21?

Comment: see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) reference for more info

Comment: @Young Seems like its not possible pre-21 versions. i havent tried yet. if i found any solutions i will update the answer.

Comment: if you find my answer is worth please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Theme which you can set to your activity through manifest.

Comment: This could have been posted as a comment.